# How do I return a PDF document from TCPDF as a string?

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

The [TCPDF documentation](https://tcpdf.org/docs/srcdoc/tcpdf/class-TCPDF/#_Output) is very useful:

> `Output( $name = 'doc.pdf', $dest = 'I' )`
>
> Send the document to a given destination: string, local file or browser. In the last case, the plug-in may be used (if present) or a download ("Save as" dialog box) may be forced.
>
> The method first calls Close() if necessary to terminate the document.

... very useful indeed. It tells me that what I want is possible, but doesn’t begin to tell me *how*. Is there any documentation on the various options for `$dest`, what they are and what they do?

Comment: Took some finding in the 25k line file but you can see the options here: https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF/blob/master/tcpdf.php#L7622 it may take a while to load ;p

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I used tcpdf many times and saved it :). Just check:

I : send the file inline to the browser (default). The plug-in is used if available. The name given by name is used when one selects the "Save as" option on the link generating the PDF.

D : send to the browser and force a file download with the name given by name.

F : save to a local server file with the name given by name.

S : return the document as a string (name is ignored).

FI : equivalent to F + I option

FD : equivalent to F + D option

E : return the document as base64 mime multi-part email attachment (RFC 2045)

Answer (score 3):

The documentation on the project’s own site is lacking, but the [documentation for the Ruby gem](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rfpdf/1.17.1/TCPDF%3AOutput) has the information we need:

> ### @param string :dest
>
> Destination where to send the document. It can take one of the following values:
>
> **I**: send the file inline to the browser (default). The plug-in is used if available. The name given by name is used when one selects the “Save as” option on the link generating the PDF.
>
> **D**: send to the browser and force a file download with the name given by name.
>
> **F**: save to a local server file with the name given by name.
>
> **S**: return the document as a string. name is ignored.
>
> **FI**: equivalent to F + I option
>
> **FD**: equivalent to F + D option

So to return it as a string, we want `Output('ignored.pdf', 'S');`.